# Remove first character in a folder name

Tags: command-line

How can I remove the first letter from  a directory name? for example:
Folder is named as "AFolder_01" how can I rename it to "Folder_01"

The reason for my question is that I have list of folders and I want to rename all these folders at once by removing the first letter.
I found this code online to remove the last character(s):

```
  while IFS= read -r dir; do [[ -d $dir ]] && mv -i "$dir" "${dir%?}"; done <all.txt
```

1. How can this code be revised to remove the first letter?
   i.e. In my example  rename "AFolder_01" to "Folder_01"
2. How can this code be revised to add charterer back at the beginning of the folder name:
   i.e. in my example rename "Folder_01"  to "AFolder_01"

Comment: As to no. 2 - how to add a character to a file name... seriously ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you have your directory name in a variable (e. g. `dir`), you can:

```
mv "$dir" "${dir:1}"
```

This will strip the first character from the variable.  I shall leave sanity-checking that the new directory does not yet already exist up to you.

To add something to the beginning (e. g. the letter `A`):

```
mv "$dir" "A$dir"
```